# is there a way to make a list of optional params? python

Tags: python, django, parameters, optional-parameters

Let's say I have a function with one / two option but what if I want to add more later on and more more? Is there a way to make it work without much hassle?

```
def json_response_message(status, message, option=(), option1=()):
    data = {
        'status': status,
        'message': message,
    }
    data.update(option)
    data.update(option1)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

so I can use it like:

```
json_response_message(True, 'Hello', {'option': option})
```

Comment: You could make use of `*args` or `**kwargs`: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I tried it with `**kwargs` but when I input more options It would say something like `json_response_message() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you want to pass an actual dictionary `json_response_message(True, 'Hello', {'option': option})`, just have a single `options=None` argument. If you want to pass arbitrary keyword arguments `json_response_message(True, 'Hello', option=option)`, then you need to use `**kwargs` *and unpack the dictionary when calling the function*: `json_response_message(True, 'Hello', **{'option': option})`.

Comment: @Tsuna Did you add `**kwargs` as a param in your function signature? e.g. `def json_response_message(status, message, **kwargs):` Also, if you do want to use keyword args, then you also have to pass the keyword identifier when you call your function: e.g. `json_response_message(True, 'Hello', option={'option': option})`... I'm assuming you want to pass dicts as your option arguments.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong problem, rather than constantly extending a function, work out what you actually want and figure out how to address that, you shouldn't need to constantly extend a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def json_response_message(status, message, **kwargs):
    data = {
        'status': status,
        'message': message,
    }

    data.update(kwargs)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

And

```
json_response_message(True, 'Hello', option=option, option1=option1) # etc...
```

or, alternatively

```
json_response_message(True, 'Hello', **{"option": option, "option1": option1})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using variable length arguments `*args`. They are prefixed with `*` in function arguments. Try out this example.

```
def json_response_message(status, message, *options):
data = {
    'status': status,
    'message': message,
}
for option in options:
    data.update(option)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

You then would call your function with as many parameters as you wanted.
`json_response_message(True, 'Hello', {'option': option}, {'option1': option})`

See http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/ for simplified further explanation.